# How/why is switch made from equation to inequality for certificate of optimality for dual problem in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

I am reading Chapter 7 Linear Programming in *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al.

I don't get how they switch from an equation to an inequality specifically the part highlighted in red/pink regarding the multiplier $y_1 + y_3 ≥ 1$ instead of $y_1 + y_3 = 1$

[image: linear programming page]

Answer (score 0):

If the required conditions are met then you have

$$ x_1 + 6x_2 \leq (y_1+y_3)x_1 + (y_2+y_3)x_2 = y_1 x_1 + y_2 x_2 + y_3(x_1 + x_2) \leq 200y_1 + 300y_2 + 400y_3$$

By looking at the leftmost and rightmost expressions you get the inequality you want.

Comment: but how do we end up getting $≥$. I think that shows $≤$.

Comment: @heretoinfinity That shows that if $y_1+y_3 \geq 1$ and $y_2+y_3 \geq 6$, then the claimed upper bound on $x_1+6x_2$ holds. You need to lower bound the $y$'s in order to show the first inequality.